# ECS task can't pull container after defining execution role

Tags: docker, amazon-web-services

I have existing task running on ECS cluster top of EC2 and now I would like to use secrets from Secret Manager. Secrets support need execution role which I have defined. Execution role has `arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy` policy which should give access to pull containers from ECR when repository is owned by same account.

I don't know what I'm missing but as soon as I defined execution role my tasks will fail with error `CannotPullContainerError: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for xxx, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'`

I have read the documentation now multiple times but I don't understand why the image can't be pulled when execution role is defined. As soon as I remove the execution role tasks are working but I can't use secrets.

How I can grant access to ECR with execution role? ECR repositories are owned by our account which is same we are running ECS tasks.

Comment: As it stated, have you done the `docker login` command? To get the command you need to use `aws ecr get-login` with the aws cli. It will then print a long command to your console that you copy and paste.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get it. In where I should do `docker login`? It's AWS ECS Cluster where `ecs-agent` is pulling the container. I don't know where `aws ecr get-login` fits in here?

Comment: I think I misunderstood what you're trying to do. So from what I understand, you have the ECR repos made, and the Docker images are pushed to your ECR repo. You're then trying to create and run a task in ECS, and then that's when you're getting the pull error?

Comment: @tero in case you found a fix for this, mind sharing? I'm running into the same exact issue

Comment: @punkbit I think it was bug in ECS. It only happened when we tried to update instances and services same time. After that I have always updated our infrastructure (instances, databases and so on) separately from services we have had zero issues.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into exactly the same problem today, cycling all EC2 instances in the ECS cluster "fixed" it.